# How i can pass the third parameter into the form validation callback function which is field name?

Tags: codeigniter, validation

here is the validation code :

```
public function registration () {
//
//
// -- code
      $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required|callback__check_length[6,10]');

}


   function _check_length($input, $min, $max)
    {
        $length = strlen($input);

        if ($length <= $max && $length >= $min)
        {
            return TRUE;
        }
        elseif ($length < $min)
        {
            $this->form_validation->set_message('_check_length', 'Minimum number of characters is ' . $min);
            return FALSE;
        }
        elseif ($length > $max)
        {
            $this->form_validation->set_message('_check_length', 'Maximum number of characters is ' . $max);
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
```

it is giving me error :
Message: Missing argument 3 for Person::_check_length(), called in C:\wamp64\www\abc\system\libraries\Form_validation.php on line 744 and defined

Answer (score 1):

You can do so by exploding the 2nd param. CI doesn't seem to support 3 params in function args for form validation rules:

```
public function _check_length($input, $minmax) {

    $minmax = explode(',', $minmax);
    $min = $minmax[0];
    $max = $minmax[1];

    $length = strlen($input);

    if ($length <= $max && $length >= $min) {
        return TRUE;
    } elseif ($length < $min) {
        $this->form_validation->set_message('_check_length', 'Minimum number of characters is ' . $min);
        return FALSE;
    } elseif ($length > $max) {
        $this->form_validation->set_message('_check_length', 'Maximum number of characters is ' . $max);
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

You also don't have to have your own function to do this. You can simply use `min_length[x]` and `max_length[x]` rules.

https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/form_validation.html#rule-reference